Getting Coordination Models fileName and Path in active document
Hi there people and robots
I am trying to get (and failing  doing so) the coordination models filenames and path's in my active document.
I tried using RevitLinkInstances, but it's not a revit link so returns a empty List.
I tried using ofCategory(OST_Coordination_Model), but it still gives me zero elements
I have found it using collector.OfClass(typeof(DirectShapeType)).ToElements().
FilteredElementCollector collectorTwo = new FilteredElementCollector(doc);

ICollection<Element> revitLinksShape = collectorTwo.OfClass(typeof(DirectShapeType)).ToElements();

foreach(var element in revitLinksShape)
{
     DirectShape directShape = fileRef as DirectShape;

     if(directShape != null)
     {
        // why does it become null???
     }
     else
     {
         var directShapeType = fileRef as DirectShapeType;
         if(directShapeType != null)
         {
             DirectShapeTypeOptions directTypeOptions = 
                             directShapeType.GetOptions();

         }
     }
 }

I am able to retrieve its name. But I am trying to get the file location! What am missing?
Do I need to make some jedi stuff to make it become some other document, or file?
I tried converting it to DirectShape, but it becomes null (and I am not even sure it would help me to find it's file path)
In resume, I want the active document coordination model's name's and path's.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The thread on Coordination Model not visible gave me more hints about what you may be talking about than your question itself.

You say you found it using collector.OfClass(typeof(DirectShapeType)).ToElements(). That sounds good. You add "with the last one". I have no idea what that is supposed to mean.

If you found it using the collector you list, the problem is solved. So, is your true question "How can I determine the name and location?" Please clarify.

@JeremyTammik sorry for my bad writing and not clarifiyng my goals. I am trying to get this coordination model File Name and Path. But the only way I've been able to 'get' this elements where as DirectShapeType. I am not seeing some converting to some other class to get theses properties (Path)?

Ok, I've managed to find a way.
I can find it's path using:
.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.DIRECTCONTEXT3D_SOURCE_ID)

So this is how i ended up getting my coordination model file name and location
        FilteredElementCollector collectorTwo = new FilteredElementCollector(doc);
        ICollection<Element> revitLinksShape = collectorTwo.OfClass(typeof(DirectShapeType)).ToElements();

        // Itera por todas as referências externas para buscar modelos de coordenação
        foreach (var fileRef in revitLinksShape)
        {
                var directShapeType = fileRef as DirectShapeType;

                if(directShapeType != null)
                {
                    Parameter coordModelPathParam = directShapeType.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.DIRECTCONTEXT3D_SOURCE_ID);
                    if (coordModelPathParam != null)
                    {
                        // Get the file path from the parameter
                        string filePath = coordModelPathParam.AsString();

                        // Display the file path
                        TaskDialog.Show("Coordination Model Path", $"File 
                                                 Path: {filePath}");
                    }
                }
         }

The answer was just right there... I just needed to calm down and analyze the element.
